# Android Time Zones

Tags: android, timezone

I want to simply display the time zones of different countries and cities in Android application. I am creating an application for Weather updates which requires the local time of the country and the city of which weather is displayed.
thanks

Codes used:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM d, yyyy, h:mm a"); 
TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"); 
System.out.println(utc.getID()); 
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(utc); 
Date now = gc.getTime(); 
System.out.println(format.format(now));
```

Comment: I was looking for a solution without using any external api and i found a solution from here DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM d, yyyy, h:mm a");
TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
System.out.println(utc.getID());
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(utc);
Date now = gc.getTime();
System.out.println(format.format(now));

Comment: It does'nt seem to work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();

DateTime dtNewYork = dt.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York"))
```

Or for time zone you can use

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Kolkata");
```

This is the reference [Link](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Gr8 +1 it deserve +1 dont you think? :) well +1 for a good question and a valid try